# getline can't get the first line of the file

Tags: c++, getline

Hi I am new here and i need help for my assignment. I want to read data from a file. I've used getline but it wont read the first line inside the file, can someone help me please?
Here is my code:

```
void test(std::ifstream& infile, string& a, string& b, string& c) 
{
   infile >> a;
   infile >> b;
   infile >> c; 
}

int main() 
{
   ifstream file_("Level1.txt");
   string line;
   string a, b, c;

   while (getline(file_, line))
   {
       test(file_, a, b, c);
   }

   cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
   return 0;
}
```

in my file:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

but output:

```
bb cc
```

Comment: You don't see the first line in the output, because you don't print it. The `getline` function read it, and then in the `test` function you read the input from the other two lines. Perhaps you want `while (file_ >> a >> b >> c) {cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n'; }`?

Comment: Copy/paste programming at its best!

Answer (score 3):

`Getline` is getting the current line, so your strings look like this

```
a = "bb"
b = "cc"
c = ""
```

since you have already read the fist line and it is stored in `line` .You can just check if the file is open and then call your test function since it will start at the beginning of the file without skipping the first line.

```
if(file_.is_open())
{
    test(file_, a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: OHH i didnt notice that my first line is alr stored in line! thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

If the stream supports [peek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek) interface (which it generally does support), you might want to check your loop condition to be like this:

```
while (file_.peek() != EOF)
```

This will do the trick (and will do exactly as I *thought* eof() would behave).

Comment: `while (!file_.eof())` [No, no, no, no.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You might want to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Yyyyeeeeah. This answer must be changed for sure. What about `while (file_.peek() != EOF)`? Should be working in most of the cases.

Comment: @iehrlich In this case Omar Martinez answer looks more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe changing `test` to return the stream and doing `while(test(file_, a, b, c)){}` depending if the OP needs to keep reading values.

Comment: @NathanOliver not really, because it changes the desired semantics of the code by reducing the number of iterations in the initial loop to 1.

Comment: Alright anyway I changed the answer to be less ignorant :)

Comment: yea! i didnt noticed the getline stored the first string into line and while (file_.peek() != EOF) works~ thanks guys!

Comment: It's still a poor answer - you're only checking that _one_ more character can be read, but extraction into three entire tokens are then attempted.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Considering the OP's sample resembles a real application, it is written in a way it expects input data in triplets. In a protected environment, we might expect that, if the message is received, it complies to the protocol - the transport layer must ensure that. That's why I assume `peek()` to be sufficient.

Comment: I see your point but think that's a bad idea, particularly in beginner code. If for no other reason than no transport layer protocol commonly used today will protect you against a truncated data stream. Just ensure that you have a full record before you attempt to do things with it; this is really easy, as shown in a comment under the question.